# How to Query X above the MIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I am trying to get .1 above the min for column X sorted by Y in A

What I have so far is:
      Select MIN(X), Y
      From A
      Where MIN(X) > (Min(x)+.1) <--- (if only computers did what i wanted them to not what i asked them to)
      Group by Y

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select x, y
from a
where x > (select min(x) + 0.1 from a);
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully, it can help you:

```
SELECT min(x), y FROM a
WHERE x > (select (min(x) + 0.1) from a)
GROUP BY y;
```